# scaling issue in SWT on 4k Monitors

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, screen-resolution

When I Project my laptop (2k resolution) to a 4k monitor in Duplicate mode, my views are not displayed same as that of my laptop. For example, Some labels are cropped, Some icons are too small, buttons are cut-off etc.. How do I solve this issue.

PS : Had the same issue when I projected to 4k monitor in Extended mode. The issue was solved by using `-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true` command, but not working for duplicate mode.